# read user input without interruption in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to grep the user command into a variable.
If the command begins with specific words I'm redirecting the command into another shell (not BASH), if not it will run regularly on bash.
When I'm using "read" I lose the BASH prompt then I'm unable to auto-complete, backspace etc.

My goal is:

if I type for example `ls -la` the command will not run and will be assigned into  variable:

```
user@machine:~$ ls -la

user_command = 'ls -la'
```

if the command is not other shell command (not BASH)

```
eval $user_command
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: It sounds like you want a custom command interpreter that behaves in every way like bash except it will look for certain prefixes. You may want to look into customizing the source code of `bash`.

Comment: Please explain clearly as to what you want to achieve

Comment: `read -i` allows you to use the `readline` library to handle user input.

Comment: I find it very unclear what you actually want to do and why... it sounds like you have an interesting idea, I just don't know what it is.

Comment: I might be misinterpreting something, but why is `read`, `grep`, or `evil` needed here? Why not just `user_command="$(ls -la)"` and then check if it begins with something?

Comment: Please be aware of the security hazards when misusing `eval` http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to :  invoke some specific commands through another shell instead of bash

You could define a function for each of those commands

exemple:

```
ls () { # function that, instead of bash, launch 'ls' through ksh
    ksh -c "ls $*"
}
```

that way, with each function's name matching the command you want to run with another shell (edit the inside of the function accordingly if it needs to be run with another shell than ksh)

Place those function in specific user's "~/.bashrc" files.

Answer (score -1):

You could write your implementation of `ls` and place it in `~/bin/ls`.
Give full permissions to this file

Comment: It don't think the OP is only trying to deal with `ls`.

Comment: If he wants *every command that starts with the string foobar_*, how will you implement that? There are infinitely many commands.

Comment: If you are building an interpreter, you have to implement the commands you want to support. I did not get your point.

Comment: Thanks cppcoder, but it doesn't solve my problem.. I want to have regular bash prompt while the user's command is captured.